# Import error for asynchat and asyncore in Python 2.7.3

Tags: python-2.7, importerror

I am using  `ARM Cortex-A9 processor` with `Linux Ångström distribution`. I have  `Python 2.7.3` which I have built using `Openembedded` project.

I am trying to use `Supervisord process monitor` on my system, but when I try to run the same, it gives following error:

> root@myDevice:~# supervisord Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/asynchat.py", line 52, in  ImportError: No
>   module named asyncore

I understand that my installed `python` package is probably incomplete and I will need to install packages to take care of this. I have `opkg and pip` which I use to install packages.

The question is:

Which package do I need to install so that the `asyncore` and `asynchat` modules will become available to my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you already have `asynchat.py` in you lib module just try to make a new file in 
`/usr/lib/python2.7` name it `asyncore.py` and insert this:
https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/asyncore.py
inside it.

note that you need to be system administrator.
use it in bash terminal like:

`$ cd /usr/lib/python2.7` 
`$ ls` => to check if you are in the correct lib 
`$ nano asyncore.py` => you can use any other text editor available in your system. 
copy paste the module inside it and save.

Note:

Check again if there is asynchat.py and asyncore.py in your lib using:
`$ ls`

Comment: Hi Heartagramir, thanks for the reply, it worked in my case and now got the supervisord up and running.....just had to deal with a few indentation error after I copied the contents in asyncore.py...it happened in places where there was line break ("\") to avoid long code lines

Comment: @AT22 Probably, in my own module there are slashes for new lines and it works well... it might happen because of editor maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Install the module using pip:

```
python -m pip install pyasynchat
```

Found Here: https://pypi.org/project/pyasynchat/